# Creating new users and grant them privileges

Tags: django, privileges

Hi i'm working with django and on my project i need to create users that have privileges, right now i'm doing this:

```
def signAdmin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            user_form.save()
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            user.is_staff = True
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
    else:
        user_form = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response(
        'register.html',
        {
            'user_form': user_form
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

but doesn't work, I've tried a few things but they have not worked for me, could you tell me how to do this? thank you.

Comment: 1)https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization

Comment: 2) `user = user_form.save(commit=False); user.is_staff = True; user.save()`

Answer (score 2):

Are you missing a `user.save()` after you set is_staff = True?

Secondly, if this is the only permission you need, setting it this way is OK. But if you need to do anything more involved, you may want to check django's permissions or one of the modules built around permissions (https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/). These allow you to create groups of permissions and add/remove users to the group and makes permission checking easier.